# Double clicking on an ics file to add to my google calendar?

Tags: windows-10, google-calendar

It's been a decade since this question has been posed here and the answers there have been outdated for nearly that long.

There is absolutely no reason why it should be difficult to configure double clicking an ics file on Windows 10 to automatically add an event to one's Google calendar.

So what's the current solution?

Comment: Apparently this question referred to a question that was originally posted in [su] -> [Automatically open ICS files in Google Calendar](https://superuser.com/q/44191/152004). Opening files by double-clicking them is a feature that depends mainly on operating system settings. Better to ask in [su].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about operating system settings. It might be on-topic in [su]. Alternatively, questions asking for  sofware recommenations can be asked in [softwarerecs.se].